# Use my local docker registry instead of minikube's

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am using minikube as my kubernetes cluster. I would like to know if there is a way to redirect minikube's docker environnement to my local environnement instead of doing the opposite with the following command:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

The problem when using the latest is that when I build a image it is destroyed whenever minikube is deleted and has to be rebuilt everytime which takes 30-40 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your host's docker for minicube, you can just do

```
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

It does not requires any VMs, works fast and use your host's docker. But prefer docker version 1.13

Comment: That is a good thing to know. But I keep getting this error "Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.42.12:8443: getsockopt: no route to host
" since i tried to start it locally

Comment: How do i find the corrext one ? or even override the oone that is pinged ? @delfer

Comment: Try ```rm -rf $HOME/.kube &&
mkdir $HOME/.kube &&
touch $HOME/.kube/config &&
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/config &&
sudo -E ./minikube start --vm-driver=none```